# Play 2 - stopping file upload mid-request, during BodyParser parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, playframework-2.0, netty

I am working on a Play 2 webapp where I let clients upload arbitrarily large files and make the server work on them chunk by chunk, before even the upload is complete, using `play.api.libs.iteratee._` and custom `BodyParser`s.

What I want to do is enable the server to "break" or "abort" the upload while it happens, so that the browser doesn't transfer the whole file.

I initially thought that putting the `BodyParser`'s `Iteratee` in the `Error` state would do the trick, but when I do it, the upload continues, the chunks are just being discarded. Throwing an exception in an `Enumeratee` that takes part in the process doesn't stop the upload either.

The only solution I can think of that **should** work is upload the file via Ajax and having a separate connection with the client's browser open (a WebSocket for example). When the server decides to terminate the file upload it would push a special command to a browser and the client-side javascript would [abort the upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#how-to-cancel-an-upload).

My question would be is there a way of terminating the upload directly from the Play app without delegating it to browser's javascript?